# In Flash CS5.5, I want to publish for iPhone and iPhone4. Do I need my stage to be 640x960?

Tags: ios, air, resolution, flash-cs5.5

I understand that in the Air for IOS settings you can set the Resolution to High.  However, when I do, and I install the app on my 3gs and my iphone4, the results are different.

I'd like to know what is the proper way of setting up a project,  and the proper way of publishing it to suite both resolution devices.

1. Stage Dimensions in the fla
2. What should my stageScaleMode be set to?
3. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to my own question is this... 
[read Renaun Erickson's post](http://renaun.com/blog/2011/03/developing-for-both-retina-and-non-retina-ios-screens-using-air-2-6). He explains nicely.

The long answer.
In my situation, (never actually going to be submitted to app store) because I don't have the luxury of vector assets, scaling dynamically at runtime is not going to produce good results.  I ended up using the following...

- a stage of 960x640
- stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
- stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

This is not ideal in most situations and It is not recommended.  
Recommended would be to create all of your assets in Vector,  then using flash's [screenResolutionX & screenResolutionY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html), you can scale assets at runtime.
This is much more to find on the subject, and I will but this got me through the quick and dirty job I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

For flow / liquid layout, I update display based upon stage width and height:

```
stage.stageWidth
stage.stageHeight
```

You can also target iPad and handle full-screen with the same IPA.

Stage scale mode should be no scale:

```
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing.  If I publish for High Resolution in the settings,  and make my stage 640x960,  It looks great on iPhone4 (retina display).  However, on the 3gs, when i install the app,  Everything is huge and way too big for the display.   BUT,  if I keep the stage 320x480,  and scale my images down it looks kind of junky on the iphone4.

Comment: btw, thanks for your response.  I'm just in robot mode.  I've got to deliver something pretty soon and this kind of just snuck up on me.